Hi, I am trying to solve this scyther exercises and unable to find any helping material to watch how to write the code
These are the protocls which I need to verify in scyther.
I, R :      Principal
Ki, Kr :    Key
Ni, Nr :    Nonce
pk :        Principal -> Key

I->R:  { I,R,Ki,Ni }pk(R)
R->I:  { I,R,Ni,Nr }Ki, { Kr,Nr }pk(I)
I->R:  { I,R }Kr


I, R, S :   Principal
Kir     :   Key
Ni      :   Nonce
k       :   (Principal, Principal) -> key

I->S: { I,R,Ni }k(I,S)
S->I: { I,R,Kir,Ni , { I,R,Kir,Ni }k(R,S) }k(I,S)
I->R: { Ni }Kir, { I,R,Kir,Ni }k(R,S)
R->I: { Ni }Kir

I tried to watch some youtube tutorials but there isn't any information on how to declare the variables and stuff.
If someone can point me towards the source where can I find the documentation or help me solve these I will be very grateful.

Update:
just found a manual and solved the problems now the problem is the second question has a few attacks to be resolved
